page doesn't change when I use router.back() in i18n-nuxt
when I navigate to "/profile" from "/" and then click to change language, route changes to "it/profile"
and then when I click on back button:
<Button @click="router.back()" :noBg="true">{{ t('back') }}</Button>
the page doesn't navigate to "/it" it just back to "/profile"
I want when in homepage I navigate to "/profile" and then click to change language the route changes to "it/profile" and then when I click on back button it navigate to "/it/"

Nice issue, how i would try to fix this issue is to create a custom method for router.back() and check if router.back(-i) has the same last segment then increment i... another solution is to store last route in a store, and for router back to take route from store ... good luck
